# str_replace só substitui a segunda array

Tags: php, array

Olá,

Estou com um problema que já tentei consertar de várias formas, mas não consigo!
Já procurei sobre a função `str_replace()` no [php.net](http://php.net) e nada!

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$cod = '192.168.1.1';
$char = '300';

$arrayFind = array('[cod]', '[char]');
$arrayReplace = array($cod, $char);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayFind); $i++) {
$response = str_replace($arrayFind[$i], $arrayReplace[$i], '[cod]/[char]');
}
```

O `str_replace()` só substitui o `[char]`, sou novato com PHP e gosto muito, mas estou muito confuso agora!

Comment: Um problema é que a variável `$response` tá perdida ali no meio sem interação. Mas, já tentou isso `$arrayFind = array('[cod]', '[char]');`
`$arrayReplace = array($cod, $char);`
`echo str_replace($arrayFind, $arrayReplace, '[cod]/[char]');` ?

Comment: Sim! Já tentei várias formas, etc.. e nenhuma funcionou! Por isso tive que fazer uma pergunta aq na SOpt :/

Comment: O que tem na variável `$cod` e `$char` ?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer coisa.. `$cod = '123'; $char = 'abc';`

Comment: é que já pensou que pode tá passando **qualquer coisa** errada ? ao invés de uma string, um array ?

Comment: Bom, se for nesse caso, aqui comigo é: `$cod = '192.168.1.1'; $char = '300';`

Comment: [Clique aqui](http://ideone.com/diA3km) e veja o **stdout**.

Comment: Opa valeu! Funcionou certinho aqui! Vou procurar saber mais ;)

Comment: Seria legal, quando perguntar, inserir o que deseja obter como resposta e o que está sendo obtido. Dessa forma deixará mais claro o que está querendo fazer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$cod = '192.168.1.1';
$char = '300';

$arrayFind = array('[cod]', '[char]');
$arrayReplace = array($cod, $char);

$response = str_replace($arrayFind, $arrayReplace, '[cod]/[char]');

//$response = 192.168.1.1/300
```

Comment: Explique um pouco mais sua resposta para ajudar outras pessoas também.